# Stardog server start with license key : wrong STARDOG_HOME

Tags: macos, bash, path, environment-variables, stardog

I'm on MAC OSX. I added these lines in my ~/.bash_profile :

```
PATH="/usr/local/stardog/bin:${PATH}"
export STARDOG_HOME=/data/stardog
export PATH
```

Then, in command line, I execute

`cp stardog-licence-key.bin $STARDOG_HOME` as the [quick-start documentation](http://docs.stardog.com/quick-start/) states.

But, this seems useless, because when I execute `sudo stardog-admin server start`, it says :

```
A Stardog license was not found.
The license file 'stardog-license-key.bin' 
should be in your Stardog Home directory 'xx/xx'.
```

xx/xx is the current directory when I launch this command ... but stardog home directory is supposed to be /data/stardog, not my working directory !

How to tell stardog his *actual* home directory ?

Comment: I did exactly what you described and it worked fine.  After you edited your `.bash_profile` did you try in a new terminal window or an existing one?  If the latter, that might be the problem, changes to your profile won't take affect in existing windows.

Comment: Yeap, sorry I didn't clarify that but I opened a new terminal window.
Actually, the command "stardog-admin server start" only works if I got the license key in my working directory.

Comment: Following your exact steps works for me, it reads the license from the exported `STARDOG_HOME` in my bash profile.  I'm on 10.9.4 using the Apple Java 6 JDK.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but you should append to the system's `PATH`, not replace it. What you have will make e.g. `ls` and `cp` unavailable unless you specify their full paths.

Comment: Yeap that's true. I edited my post consequently ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine (and sorry), I did not mention some elements : I executed the command `stardog-admin server start` with **sudo** (as seen in the last edit of my question).

**Reasons :**
I launched this command with **sudo** because I needed some permissions to start stardog properly.

**Problem :** With **sudo**, stardog home is not the one defined in my previous .bash_profile anymore.

**Solution :** I give (owner) permissions to myself on the directory $STARDOG_HOME with the command `sudo chown -R myUsername /data/stardog`

Open a new bash, type `stardog-admin server start` without **sudo**, it works.